# remove values in one array from another

Tags: java, arrays

Anyone know how I can remove values in one array from another, without using ArrayList? I'd think this has been asked before, but I could only find solutions using ArrayList.

For example

```
int[] set01 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] set02 = {1, 2};
int[] set03;

//function to remove set02 from set01, yielding set03
//set03 = {3, 4, 5, 6}
```

an extract from the actual script:

```
//just a placeholder, length of 'ptSet' is variable
//these are point coordinates {x, y} - the actual values don't matter
float[][] ptSet = new float[100][2];

//populate ptSet with 100 points

//'set02' of original question
int[] cchOrdered = {1, 12, 22, 32, 54};

//'set03' of original question
int[] eligiblePts = new int[0];

//compare 'cchPts' with 'ptSet'
for (int j = 0; j < ptSet.length; j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < cchOrdered.length; k++) {
    //this doesn't work, as the nested loop invalidates any duplicate checks
    if (!(cchOrdered[k] == j)){
      eligiblePts = (int[]) append(eligiblePts, j);
    }
  }
}
```

again, sorry if my code is not as clean as it could be... still learning here :S

Comment: to clarify this can be language independent... it's really about the logic - especially since I'd like to write my own function rather than use/import other functions.

Comment: You can use ArrayList and convert it to array. What is the reason behind not using ArrayList?

Comment: The main problem for using array in this case is the size of set03 cannot be determined prior, ie while declaring it.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to JAVA, so what I'm saying may not actually be a good argument - but I'm trying to avoid using ArrayList as the array values are coming from another method inside a class... so I don't want to end up with ArrayLists and objects all mixed up.
For your second comment, would it be possible to 'append' to set03?

Comment: Please post the full code. Then we can help.

Comment: the original post has been edited to include an extract of the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for this is using an ArrayList. Since you don't want to use it you can do something like below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] set01 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        int[] set02 = {1, 2};

        //assume set01 having more elements than set02 array 
        int[] set03 = Arrays.copyOf(set01, set01.length);            

       // sorting array is optional if you know the arrays are sort.
        Arrays.sort(set01);
        Arrays.sort(set02);

        for(int value :set02){
            set03 = ArrayUtils.removeElement(set03, value);          
        }

        for(int value:set03){
           System.out.println("set03 array :"+ value);

        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great, thanks Minoli Alles. As I'm trying to use this in Processing, is there an alternative method to:
    boolean contains = IntStream.of(set02).anyMatch(x -> x == value);

Comment: @fig8 welcome :) then we can use ArrayUtils.removeElement(array,element) for this. I'l edit the answer accordingly.